# I did not flag all these posts as Very Low Quality

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, low-quality-posts

And yet, the flag dialog claims I did:

[image]

It's not every post, but it's a lot of them.  For instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67422085/208273) and [this now-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67410053/) (though it stopped showing up on that answer once I flagged it as NAA).

[A few other users noticed the same thing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52144795#52144795), with one person speculating that it might be caused by other users having flagged the post as VLQ.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This bug has now been fixed network wide. In a certain case of flagging logic, it was checking all flags instead of just your flags to see if you've already raised a flag. I've fixed the check and you should no longer see this issue anymore. Thanks for reporting, and let me know if you're still seeing it anywhere!